# Alfresco - Execute custom action using web service client not working

Tags: alfresco

I have created a rule for a space in which added simple workflow.
If user approves file from this workflow then, this file is get moved to another space.

Now I want to approve files using alfresco web service client. For this I am using following code, but somehow it is not moving file to another space (not executing approve action)

```
ActionServiceSoapBindingStub actionService = WebServiceFactory.getActionService();
Rule[] rules = actionService.getRules(parentRef, new RuleFilter());
for (int i = 0; i < rules.length; i++) {
  Rule rule = rules[i];
  if(rule.getTitle().equals("Upload workflow rule")) {
    ActionExecutionResult[] results = actionService.executeActions(predicete, 
       new Action[{rule.getAction()});
  }
}
```

Thanks, Yogesh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution for this, just need to call CommandServlet with specific parameters.

Example - (http://localhost:8080/alfresco/command/workflow/approve/workspace/SpacesStore/0000-0000-0000)

Here "0000-0000-0000" is node id on which I wanted to execute workflow approve.

Thanks.